# Using respectively- "Signal strength was 20, 30, 40 dB at floors 1,2,3 respectively."

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, adverbial-phrases

In the following sentence,

> "Signal  strength was 20, 30, 40 dB at floors 1,2,3 respectively."

Should I use ***was*** or ***were***?

Should the unit dB be used just for the last input of the list or every input?

Should I use ***floors*** or ***floor***?

Comment: Personally, I would say "Signal strength **on** (?) the first, second and third floors were 20, 30, and 40 dB, respectively." I think it depends on the subject, my subject is plural so I used plural form of the verb. However, I am not native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, for the first answer "was" is correct.

For the second one, dB should be used for each input. The way you have written is also correct, i feel.

Floors is correct because you are mentioning three floors.

Comment: "was" is correct, but it's worth pointing out that, if the original sentence said "strengths," then "were" would be the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

"Signal strength was at 20db, 30db, 40db for their respective floors 1, 2 and 3."

Works in a general sense. If you were writing a technical paper/manual I would advise relating each floor to its db level.

"Single strength on floor 1 was 20db, floor 2 was 30db, and floor 3 was 40db."

This sacrifices brevity for clarity for the reader.